# need help on my INSERT INTO statement

Tags: insert-into

I am getting Syntax error in Insert INTO statement error but i couldn't find the problem.

try
            {

```
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO gelir VALUES blok=@blok,[yatıran isim]=@yatıran,tarih=@tarih, nerden=@odemeyer,tür=@odemetur ,tutar=@tutar, nott=@nott ", db);


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@blok", blokk);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yatıran", ad.Text);
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(tarih.Text) && tarih.Text != " ")
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarih", Convert.ToDateTime(tarih.Text));
            else
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tarih", Convert.ToDateTime("01.01.1900"));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odemeyer", odemeyer.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@odemetur", odemetur.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tutar", Convert.ToInt32(tutar.Text));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nott", not.Text);


            if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                db.Open();
            }


            // Sorgu çalıştırılır:
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            // Bağlantı kapatılır:
            db.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
```

try
            {

Thank you very much for your help

Regards

Comment: What RDBMS? What's the error? Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: INSERT INTO is pretty universal for simple queries like this, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp RDBMS is not necessarily necessary for this question. The error is Syntax error. Desired behavior is obviously to INSERT INTO. Clear problem statement is how do I build an INSERT INTO correctly. All of this can be drawn from what @Murat included here.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO gelir (blok, [yatıran isim], tarih, nerden, tür, tutar, nott) VALUES (@blok, @yatıran, @tarih, @odemeyer, @odemetur , @tutar, @nott)", db);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You're welcome :-) please mark as answer if it worked for you.